# Detect if Google Earth Plugin is in Street View mode

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin, google-street-view

I just want to know if there is any way to determine if the current Google earth plug-in is in street view mode or not.

Comment: I was referring to Google Earth plug-in on browsers. My bad

Answer (score 1):

To test if street view is enabled in the Google Earth plugin:

```
var navcontrol = ge.getNavigationControl();
var response = navcontrol.getStreetViewEnabled(); // default=false
// response: true -> enabled; false -> disabled
if (!response) {
   // to enable street view mode
   navcontrol.setStreetViewEnabled(true);
}
```

If street view is enabled by calling *setStreetViewEnabled(true)* then user will be able to interactively enter StreetView by manually zooming in (or using pegman).

Note the API docs documents calling *ge.getPlugin().streetViewEnabled(true)* but this is an error since the getPlugin() method does not exist. The correct method is calling *getNavigationControl()*.

Here's how to test if street view mode is active:

```
var la = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
var viewerOptions = la.getViewerOptions();
if (viewerOptions) {
    var state = viewerOptions.getOption(ge.OPTION_STREET_VIEW);
    if (state == ge.OPTION_STATE_ENABLED) {
        // street view mode is active
        // do something here
    }
}
// if viewerOptions is null then no modes are active
```

State can be one of three values:

```
GEPlugin.OPTION_STATE_DEFAULT  (0)
GEPlugin.OPTION_STATE_ENABLED  (1)
GEPlugin.OPTION_STATE_DISABLED (2)
```

Reference: [Interface options](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_kml_viewer_options) and [GE Plugin](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_plugin#ac5c3007e6ca69cec000d2bbfa18b95c8).